# What do I do if I have the exact same question as a question that is closed as 'too localized'?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, too-localized

I've been struggling with unnecessary blank pages at the beginning of appendices.  There are a few answers that speak to my problem, none of which have worked.  I was pleased to find another person who was in the exact same predicament as I am, who asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79137/28811).  Then I was disappointed to see that the question was closed as 'too localized':

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

I would guess that the close-voters were assuming that this question was 'extraordinarily narrow' in scope.  At first glance, it would seem that way.  However, given that I am in the *exact same situation* as the OP, it no longer seems so narrowly applicable.

What should I do?  Ask the same question again?  Somehow [suggest to reopen it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79137/remove-unnecessary-blank-page-after-creating-an-appendix-still-not-solved#comment248779_79137)?

Comment: I suspect the question was not answerable in that form which was why it was closed. That should not stop you asking a new question that includes a proper example that demonstrates the problem. If people can use the MWE  to reproduce the blank page they can probably easily say how to avoid that.

Comment: Understood -- although if that is true, then the close reason was incorrect.  Had the close reason been correct (i.e. No MWE, can't repro), then this whole meta question could have been avoided.

Comment: The close categories are fixed and somewhat inflexible, the first reason given for which "too localised" may be used is "this question is unlikely to help future visitors" which is a catch-all phrase for any question that is not phrased in a way that will get useful replies. there is not a specific "can not reproduce" close category.

Comment: I understand.  These network-wide hamfisted close-reasons really should be dealt with -- they cause so much grief.

Comment: @alx9r We are promised some changes to the close reasons, but that is down to the Powers That Be. As such, 'we' (TeX-sx regulars) use 'too localized' in the sense that David indicates: 'unlikely to help future visitors'.

Comment: @JosephWright I understand the situation.  Joel, et al have been talking about changing close reasons for forever on the SE podcast...but, no love yet :(